# WebXR: how to migrate from Oculus Go to Quest?

Tags: migration, oculusgo, oculusquest, webxr

I'm using Oculus Go controls (touchpad + trigger) in my WebXR molecular viewer (pure JavaScript + WebGL + WebXR) at https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webxr/mini.htm. To migrate from Go to Quest I'd like to know, what corresponds to "selectend event" and "xrSession.inputSources[0].gamepad.axes[0/1] on Quest?

Answer (score 0):

On the Quest thumbstick is exposed as

```
xrSession.inputSources[0/1].gamepad.axes[touchpad X, touchpad Y, thumbstick X, thumbstick Y]
```

where 0/1 correspond to the right/left hands. Therefore `axes[2,3]` should be used (instead `axes[0,1]` on the Go) to get X,Y coordinates.

See e.g. https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webxr/mini/micro3q.htm.